# jQuery find changed attribute value after changing it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not know if what I am doing is the right approach to do it. But what I am trying to do is the following.

I have a menu that a user can open and close buy clicking on the menuhead button. What I want is to save the status open or closed into my database so that when the user refreshes the page or when he logs in again the menu status is open or close as they intended.

The html button below has an attribute

```
data-menustatus="<?php echo $showam; ?>"
```

which stores the status value of the menu item from the database. 1 for open and 0 for closed.

```
<button class="btn-toggle hass-menuhead align-items-center collapsed MenuStatus" type="button" data-menuitem="accounts" data-menustatus="<?php echo $showam; ?>" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#Accounts-collapse" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="true">
          Accounts Menu
</button>
```

When the user clicks on the button I get that value and write it to the database and make it check for 1 or 0 and depending on the outcome I store 1 or 0. I use jQuery to change the `data-menustatus="<?php echo $showam; ?>"` to 1 or 0 depending on the original number. When I inspect the console I see it change to 1 when the original data is 0, as intended.

Now the problem. When I click on that same button again it now should read 1 as that is the value that jQuery changed and is showing in the console. But instead jQuery is still finding the original 0 instead of the new 1 value.

I am not a expert in jQuery and I tried this in below script. What am I doing wrong? I this not possible? All help is welcome !

```
$(document).on("click", ".MenuStatus", function () {
var MenuStatus = $(this).data("menustatus");
var MenuItem = $(this).data("menuitem");

if(MenuStatus == 1) {
    $(this).attr('data-menustatus','0');
} else {
    $(this).attr('data-menustatus','1');
}
console.log(MenuStatus);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../menu/SetMenuFilters.php",
data: {MenuStatus: MenuStatus,MenuItem: MenuItem},
success: function(data) {
},

error: function(xhr, status, error) {
 if(xhr.status&&xhr.status==401){
p.error('Session is broken, login again.'); 
setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 4000);
}else{
alert("Something went wrong, try again later."); 
       } }
});
});
```

Comment: Why are you saving opened/closed menus in the database? Using localStorage for UI things like that is more suitable. If this is a learning excercise forget I wrote anything.

Comment: It is for learning excercise and local is not keeping when user deletes cookies etc.

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is separate from cookies. Also if you remove cookies and delete website data, maybe it is not that much of a problem to open/close those menus again. But sure, for learning that's fine.

Comment: You are probebly right. But good to know this to. Doing so in local storage will be a new thing to learn to. So I lll get to that in the future probebly. Thanks for assisting !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `data()` takes a new value. Try this instead:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".MenuStatus", function () {
  var MenuStatus = $(this).data("menustatus");
  var MenuItem = $(this).data("menuitem");

  if (MenuStatus == 1) {
    $(this).data('menustatus', '0');
  } else {
    $(this).data('menustatus', '1');
  }
  console.log(MenuStatus);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../menu/SetMenuFilters.php",
    data: {
      MenuStatus: MenuStatus,
      MenuItem: MenuItem
    },
    success: function (data) {},

    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      if (xhr.status && xhr.status == 401) {
        p.error('Session is broken, login again.');
        setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 4000);
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong, try again later.");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In short the reason is that jQuery handles `data` separate from HTML attributes. You can actually store whole objects calling `.data()` without DOM updates stressing the browser.

Documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks. Tried this before but I did not saw the attribute change in the console so assumed it did not worked as I expected the attribtue value to change. But checking the post data to my server it is working. Many thanks !

Comment: Yes that is a problem with learning to use `data()`, you do not see it in the DOM - but that's kind of the point. Glad to help.